# why alert don't work when we use php header function ? .i know window.location.href is solution

Tags: javascript, php

why alert function don't work in the following snippet?

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "<script>alert('Some text');</script>";
header("location:somepage.php");
?>
```

It is redirecting the user but not showing the alert . I know  window.location.href is the solution but i want the reason why this alert is not working.

thanks in advance

Comment: Because the serverside doesn't wait for the clientside to finish, so it just redirects without waiting for the alert.

Comment: You also can't send headers after the body.

Comment: i think we can send headers after body if we are using ob_start() or i am wrong?

Comment: Using outputbuffering sure, but you should instead construct your code in a way that you don't need to use outputbufferings.

Comment: Ah ok, it automatically flushes the buffer, if it's still active when the script ends.

Answer (score 4):

Because the browser will execute the redirect before waiting for DOM to load completely. Your page will tell the browser to redirect and the body of the page contain javaScript that will issue an alert after the DOM completed successfully.

And as standard practice, when using Header redirect you must exit the PHP and don't output anything before setting any header attribute.